# dynamic CSS for images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css

So, I have 'thumbnails' of images on a page.  The images are resized via CSS, hence the quotes on 'thumbnails'.  Sometimes the images are tall, and sometimes they're wide.  Obvious, right?

Right now, I'm handling this, but it's slow.  Tell me there's a better way.

_photo.html.erb (partial to call `<%= render '@photos' %>`)

```
<% image_size = FastImage.size(photo.image_url) %>
<% if image_size[0] > image_size[1] %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url, class: 'wide'), photo if photo.image_url %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url, class: 'tall'), photo if photo.image_url %>
<% end %>
```

and in the CSS...

```
img {
  &.tall {
    max-width: 220px;
    min-width: 220px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20%;
    left: -10px;
  }
  &.wide {
    max-height: 220px;
    min-height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20%;
    top: -10px;
  }
}
```

I already said, it works.  When I call that page, though, it has to think about it, and there are only 3 photos.  Obviously not a good solution.  I'd also like to center the image in it's little 200px containter.  My way just feels so... crude.

**Thoughts?**

Comment: what are the filesize of the images?

Comment: depends... 200k to 3mb?

Comment: Ignore my other comments, didn't read your code properly. In the above case, I'd instead store the image filesizes with the model, then use: `photo.filesize`. Speaking on quanity/size of images on the page, be sure to create appropriate versions of your files on upload/processing. It is wasteful to downsize the dimensions of a 3mb image using CSS - that will not reduce the transfer size.

Comment: What Damien said, the image is still 3mb even if you resize it with css. As for centering image in its container.
The following style works `{margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}`

Comment: So, I wasn't creating the thumnail version. Bottom line, I'm gonna have to do that.  That still leaves the question of positioning the image.  When I talk about size, I'm talking dimensions.  A wide image i'm going to want to move to the left.  A Tall image, I'm going to want to move up.

Comment: anything handy for vertical centering, @Neet324?

Comment: [try one of the answers from this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665798/vertical-center-an-image-without-knowing-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use javascript DOM :

**Set Class**

```
document.getElementById("img").className = "tall";
```

**Add Class**

```
document.getElementById("img").className += "wide";
```

**Remove Class**

```
document.getElementById("img").className = "";
```

Comment: how would I get the size of the images?

Comment: You can retrieve element height and width by `document.getElementById("img").style.width` and `document.getElementById("img").style.height`in JavaScript