# How to make image vertically centered?

Tags: css, wordpress

How to make those flags on the right centered vertically? Here's my contact-bar.css file (on the bottom are flags):

```
<?php
/**
 *  Terrifico
 */
global $data; ?>            
            <div id="contact-bar">
                <p class="label"><?php echo $data['top_panel_contact_text']; ?></p>
                <a class="mail" href="mailto:<?php echo $data['top_panel_email'];?>">
                    <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="phone">
                    <i class="icon-phone"></i>
                    <span><?php echo $data['top_panel_phone']; ?></span>
                </a>
            </div><!--contact-bar-->


<div id="flags" style="float: right" margin-top:10px;>
<?php if( function_exists( 'simple_language_switcher' ) ) { ?>
<div id="simple-language-switcher"><?php simple_language_switcher(); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#flags{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

For inline style try

```
<div id="flags" style="float: right; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
```

Reference: [vertical center an image without knowing dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665798/vertical-center-an-image-without-knowing-dimensions)

Other similar questions

[Using margin:auto to vertically-align a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div)

Comment: I don't know what is the CSS file for this top panel. I tried style.css and top-panel.css but no changes.

Comment: @marjanbaz I have added inline style for "flags". Let me know if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Try setting the style in inner <div>, something like this <div id="simple-language-switcher" style="float: right; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">